# Jinja multiple rendering streams

Tags: stream, jinja2

Is there any way within a jinja template to render simultaneously to multiple streams?

Lets say I want to render a (printable) quiz, with first all the questions, then all the answers at the end. Each type of question (multiple choice, matching, missing word) is a different template.

Obviously I can take two passes and have question and answer in separate templates. But I would like to do this in one pass, so as to keep the templates well organised, and also to make the python calling code more regular, without a special case to handle this situation).

What I would like to have something like multiple 'streams', similar to blocks, but which which accumulate the output of multiple templates. Obviously the below is fantasy but is there another way within jinja to do this?

```
{% streams x, y %}  {# define twp streams x and y #}
{% stream x %}
aaaa
{% endstream %}

{% stream y %}
bbbb
{% endstream %}

{% stream x %}
cccc
{% endstream %}

{% stream y %}
dddd
{% endstream %}

{{ x }}  {# renders aaaacccc #}
{{ y }}  {# renders bbbbdddd #}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering to multiple streams is not possible. A simple solution would be to call the template twice, with a `question` boolean argument, and use `if` expressions to switch between question and answer code:

```
{% if questions %}
aaaa
{% else %}
bbbb
{% endif %}

{% if questions %}
cccc
{% else %}
dddd
{% endif %}
```

Then you call the template:

```
questions_html = template.render(questions=True)
answers_html = template.render(questions=False)
```